# Evaluating limit in terms of alpha

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

In a calculus book I found:

> Evaluate the following limits in terms of the number $\alpha =\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}$
>
> i) $$
> \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin 2x}{x}
> $$

I know some techniques how to evaluate limits, but I don’t understand what it means to evaluate a limit in terms of another number alpha.

Can someone give an example of what’s expected here?

Comment: They're telling you that $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ converges as $x \to 0$, but they're not telling you what the limit is. They want you to use this limit, $\alpha$, to find out what $\frac{\sin(2x)}{x}$ converges to as a function of $\alpha$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:   write it as $\;\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin 2x}{x} = \color{red}2 \cdot \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin 2x}{\color{red}{2}x} = 2 \,\cdot\, \underbrace{
\lim_{y \to 0} \frac{\sin y}{y}}_{\alpha}\,$.

Comment: Is that even a hint anymore?

Comment: @TheoBendit May be a *strong* hint, but there still are a couple of blanks left for the OP to fill-in before it becomes a complete answer (constants in and out of $\,\lim\,$, substitution etc).

Comment: Thanks I understand now more. So you multiplied and dividedby 2 to get the limit expression into the form of alpha, just to clarify for me?

Comment: @Max Yes, that's precisely it. They wanted you to `evaluate the following limits in terms of α`, so the point was to rewrite the limit as to make something *like* $\,\alpha\,$ appear, that could be used.